# Dynamically increase hitbox of a button on mousedown, and restore on mouse up?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to make it so when you press down on a button, the hitbox of the button gets bigger, so if the user slides the mouse off the edge of the already held down button, it requires it to travel further before it no longer counts for clicking.

This is to be used on a touch screen device, where users will go to click, but slide their finger before releasing, which won't finish the click event.

I'm using the standard flash buttons (flash.display.SimpleButton), so ideally would like something that works with them - I keep looking at the hitTestState as the solution, but nothing I'm trying works.

Let's say the button starts as size 50, 50

When a user triggers a mouse_down event, I'd like it to become 100 by 100, centred as a hitbox (not the actual button, just the hit) - then on click, or release, it'll fade back to the 50,50 size.

Any ideas?

Thanks
John

Comment: John - when you say 'standard flash buttons', do you mean flash.display.SimpleButton, or fl.controls.Button, or mx.controls.Button?

Comment: Updated to include flash.display.SimpleButton, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Flash 10.1 or newer? If so, have you looked at [TouchEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html). It has size properties (`sizeX` and `sizeY`) that indicate the contact area of the touch.

Comment: I'm using 10.1, however the app is a mix of browser and mobile, therefore needs to use MouseEvents (we are not using mutilitouch).

Comment: SimpleButton makes it tricky, because it doesn't extend DisplayObjectContainer, so you can't easily find and access the existing child object to resize it, and as you've discovered, adding a new hitTestState after a click doesn't change the dimensions. It's really quite straightforward to roll your own button from a Sprite or MovieClip, which would give you full control over every aspect of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your button with a movie clip. There are any number of ways to do it, but here's one structure that works.

A smaller hit area in the up and over frames:

[image: Up Frame]

With a larger area in the down frame:

[image: Down Frame]

(Obviously you would make the hit area zero alpha, but I've coloured it so you can see what's happening.)

Then all you need is a very straightforward bit of code. Given an instance on the stage called MyButton:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var MyButton:MovieClip;
MyButton.buttonMode = MyButton.useHandCursor = true;

function handleMouseOver($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    MyButton.gotoAndStop("Over");
}

function handleMouseDown($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    MyButton.gotoAndStop("Down");
}

function handleMouseUp($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    MyButton.gotoAndStop("Up");
}

MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleMouseOver);
MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseDown);
MyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseUp);
```

If you want to re-use this several times, it can easily be refactored into a class which your MovieClips can extend.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be easier to ditch the hitbox and go for `hitTestPoint`.

So you can just add this:

```
var hitObject:Sprite = new Sprite();
//Create a new Sprite
hitObject.graphics.beginFill(0);
hitObject.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
hitObject.endFill();
//Draw a rectangle on the sprite, this is your hitbox

hitObject.alpha = 0;
//Make it invisible
hitObject.x = button.x;
hitObject.y = button.y;

addChild(hitObject);

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDownEvent);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEvent);

function mDownEvent(e:MouseEvent){
     hitObject.scaleX = hitObject.scaleY = 2;
     //When the mouse is down the object gets 2 times as big (100 pixels)

     if(hitObject.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY, true)){
         //You have clicked your hitbox
     }
}

function enterFrameEvent(e:Event){
     if(hitObject.scaleX > 1){
           hitObject.scaleX -= 0.1;
           hitObject.scaleY -= 0.1;
           //Decrease the hitbox his size when you have pressed the mouse, 0.1 is the speed the hitbox gets smaller
     }
}
```

Comment: Preferably, I'd not to have to separate code for each button, and could have this be dynamically applied to pre-existing buttons.

Comment: Well you could add this movieClip to the button using `button.addChild(hitObject)` and then you would have to remove the lines `hitObject.x = button.x` and `hitObject.y = button.y`.